# Seeking in large files with ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I'm implementing a program in C++ using ifstream that must seek in large files (~1TB). However, this fails after reading 2GB. Is there a way to get file positions, even for large files? I compile for a 32-bit windows machine.

```
std::ifstream f;
f.open( filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary );
while(true) {
    std::cout << (uint64_t)(f.tellg()) << std::endl;
    //read data
}
```

Comment: I  don't know if this actually changes anything, but have you tried using the plain C alternative of reading files?

Comment: @stefan has plain C file-position handler which size is greater than 32 bits?

Comment: @triclosan as I said: I don't know, it was just an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are compiling on a 32-bit platform, if you use `fstream`, you are going to get 32-bits access. To access large files, you need to use a platform dependent solution :

- for windows, use [_lseeki64()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yee101t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- for linux, use [lseek64()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lseek64)

Comment: I will use these functions. Thank you!